# Making a 360 degree view of an image in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a 360 degree view of an image using html. My sample code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Panorama</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Panorama — A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-sky src="images/gallery/pan0.png" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is, when I run the code, nothing is showing. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: This works fine on Firefox but not on chrome

Comment: When I run that code in safari and chrome, https://jsfiddle.net/9q0v1pf8/1/ it works fine. Are you sure your image (pan0.png) is referenced correctly?

Comment: yes. image path is correct. but, still getting a blank white screen, is there any way to modify the code so that it will work for all browsers? @Barbara Laird

Answer (score 1):

I have made changes to the code.Try this code this should work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Panorama</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Panorama — A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-assets>
            <img id="panorama" src="images/gallery/pan0.png"/>
        </a-assets>
        <a-sky src="#panorama" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```